# How to enable or disable GPS in android device programmatically in Kotlin for all api levels?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gps, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app where I have to enable GPS and if GPS is already on then function or module should respond with flow of Boolean and if GPS is off then I have to turn it on and When it turns on perfectly then turn it off and receive flow of true(Boolean). If any error occurs then an exception should be passed to the flow I have tried some codes but did not get any good results.

**Note :-**
Please include all the permissions for GPS and I am using jetpack compose and I am new at that and I do not know how to handle permission in Jetpack compose so it would be very big help to teach me how to handle permission there. And suggest me solution where it will work on all level apis. Thank you.

**My codes:-**

**My Module**

```
class GPSModule(private val context: Context) {


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
fun checkGPS():Flow<Response<Boolean>> = flow{
    val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    val response = if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
        if (manager.isLocationEnabled){
            manager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,false)
            Response.Success(true)
        }else{
            manager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,false)
            Response.Error("GPS is not working.")
        }
    } else {
        Response.Error("Device does not have GPS.")
    }

    emit(response)
}
}
```

**Response Class**

```
sealed class Response<out T> {

object Loading : Response<Nothing>()

data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Response<T>()

data class Error(val error:String):Response<Nothing>()

}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@HiltViewModel
class TestScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    gpsModule: GPSModule
):ViewModel() {

var gpsResult = ""

val _uiEvents = Channel<UIEvents> ()
val uiEvents = _uiEvents.receiveAsFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        gpsModule.checkGPS().collect {
            when(it){
                is Response.Error -> {
                    _uiEvents.send(UIEvents.ShowSnackBar(it.error))
                }
                Response.Loading -> TODO()
                is Response.Success -> {
                    gpsResult=it.data.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**My UI(Jetpack compose)**

```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@Composable
fun Tests(
    viewModel: TestScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

val context= LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    viewModel.uiEvents.collect{
        when(it){
            is UIEvents.Navigate -> TODO()
            UIEvents.PopScreen -> TODO()
            is UIEvents.ShowSnackBar -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(text = viewModel.gpsResult)
}
}
```